# Does puppeteer have a puppeteer-extra docker image?

Tags: cloud, puppeteer

I am trying to host my puppeteer inside of a docker image but I can only find a docker image for puppeteer not puppeteer-extra

I am trying to host my puppeteer on Render.com but run into issues.

Docker:

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:14

# Set a working directory within the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy both package.json and package-lock.json into the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install Node.js dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install Chromium for Puppeteer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    chromium \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the rest of your application code into the container
COPY . .

# Expose the port your Node.js application uses (if necessary)
# EXPOSE 3000

# Define the command to run your Node.js application
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: "run into issues" -- which issues, specifically?